# Flex - How does nativeApplication.icon work?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flash

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = bitmapData();
```

I'm trying to edit the bitmaps for the system tray icon, but I got an error:

> Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:BitmapData to an unrelated type Array.

What mistake did I make, or could you tell me the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Icon.bitmaps](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/desktop/Icon.html#bitmaps) is an Array of BitmapData, with one BitmapData instance for each size. You must reassign the entire array:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = new Array(bitmapData);
```

Alternatively, as the livedocs mention, you can specify all the bitmap sizes:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = 
    new Array(icon16x16.bitmapData, icon128x128.bitmapData);
```

Comment: No worries. If it answered your question to the point where you don't need to wait for a better answer, you can mark it as "the answer" by clicking the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a typecast in there such as:

SystemTrayIcon(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon).bitmaps

The SystemTrayIcon is a Windows-specific class I believe.

Comment: var sysTrayIcon:SystemTrayIcon = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon as SystemTrayIcon;

ok i tried this code also

Comment: i tried SystemTrayIcon(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon).bitmaps but got same error y ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the discussion about this topic from Adobe:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=taskbar_1.html